# Spring Sorting with Nulls_Last Handling not working

Tags: spring, sorting, spring-data-jpa

I created a sort rule like this for sorting my list:

```
Sort sort = new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC,"productOrder", Sort.NullHandling.NULLS_LAST), new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC,"producedYear", Sort.NullHandling.NULLS_LAST));
```

with this rule I want to sort the `productOrder` first, and then if the `productOrder` is the same then the `producedYear` will be compared and sorted. If there are **null values** presented, it should be sorted at the end of the list. `productOrder` will have type Long and `producedYear` will have type Double.

My Repository interface extends the JpaRepository:

```
 public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, String> {

    List<Product> findByDisabledAndValid(int disabled, int valid, Sort sort);
}
```

But the sorted list I received is containing the **null values** always at the **beginning** of the list. This means the **null values** will be sorted first, then come the `productOrder`, and finally the `producedYear` will be sorted. It seems that the **third parameter** that I defined on my **Sort.Order** method is not working.

Does anyone have an idea why? Thank you very much

Comment: Perhaps that helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37598238/jpa-are-query-hints-vendor-specific

Comment: I found it again: The definitions of query hints are vendor-specific. It is for EclipseLink, but I think for Spring it is just the same: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.7/concepts/queries006.htm  I think it depends on the data base if it works or not.

Comment: Here it works for some data bases, but for instance not for mySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401227/how-to-define-null-handling-in-spring-data-jpa-sorts?rq=1

Comment: hi @D.Braun, thank you for your hint. This means that the Sorting function go with Spring is not database provider independent? Therefore I should implement my own Sorting function to work with all database provider? Am I correct?

Comment: I found in the source code of the Sort.NullHandling, that NULLS-LAST ist just a hint for the data base: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.NullHandling.html    The Sort.Direction does not look like a hint: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.Direction.html  I think you have to implement your own null handling for all data bases.

Comment: I see, then I think I should implement my own sorting function...

Answer (score -3):

Instead of using the Sort.NullHandling.NULLS_LAST integrated with Spring, I solved the above problem by creating my own Sort function, like this:

```
Collections.sort(resultList, Comparator
                    .comparing(Product::getProductOrder, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
                    .thenComparing(Product::getProducedYear, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

Hope this help if someone also faces the same problem.

Regards!

Comment: This obviously ruins the whole advantage of sorting on the database side. Imagine what would happen if we moved database operatons (i.e. filtering, sorting) to our backend services...